# regexec and regcomp more efficient than doing strncmp myself?

Tags: c, regex, performance, c-strings

I have a string like this:

```
I am down in the town seeing a crown="larry" with a cherry="red"
```

I want to write a program that asks user what she wants. If she requests the string that should have "larry" as crown and "red" cherry, I need to return the string.

Okay, I am over simplifying the problem here. There can be many such strings and I need to parse through them and return all that matches.

Question: doing regexec and regcomp is more efficient or breaking down the string and doing strncmp?

PS: It seems that regexec would need to do some sort of comparison internally and those would have been designed to be much efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `strncmp()` is simply the wrong tool for the job; if you'd said `strstr()`, there might have been room for discussion.  You can't use `strncmp()` easily because you have to find a position to start it comparing at.

If you used `strstr()`, you'd be looking for strings such as:

```
crown="larry"
cherry="red"
```

If you use a regex, you have to compile it, and run it.  If you are searching for the two strings, you have two regexes, unless you want to write a contorted regex.  I think that for simple comparisons where you need both the strings above in either order, you might find two uses of `strstr()` quicker than one or two regexes.

It is worth measuring the difference, though.  It may depend on the implementation of `strstr()`; some are very good.  So, run measurements on the platforms you are concerned with, and choose which works better for you.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. For me, string can be: [let's play a game where teacher="larry" crown="larry" larry is a great teacher but a bad clown.] --- in this case, strstr() cannot be used efficiently, correct?

Comment: @hari: I don't see why not, but I'm not sure I understand what you're really up to.  It seems an unusual search format.  However, if you're looking for '`teacher="larry"`' then `strstr()` can do that reasonably fast in the string you show.  If you're looking for deeper comprehension of the sentence, then probably neither `strstr()` nor a regex is appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I will see what makes more sense and update you here.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are probably compiling a new regex each time you'll do a `regexec()`, that will probably be a bit slower than using `strncmp()` to check for the keyword, e.g. "crown=" and then checking if the value is "\"larry\"".

I assume you could build a system that parses the keywords and values beforehand and keeps some kind of list, dictionary or some such pointing to the string, or vice versa (each string is associated with a set of keyword="value" combinations). That could be done once, and would making the work during search easier.

But I don't know enough of your goals and your existing code to know if that makes sense for your situation.

In other words, you would have to profile this to be sure, but I guess that `strncmp()`would be more performant than the `regcomp()` and `regexec()` combinations. Regular expressions are, of course, far more flexible, but I don't think you need that here.

**Addition**

Assuming that '=' is not a character that will be found in your lines very often, you can of course use `strchr()` to find each occurrence of '=' in the string, and then check if the next character is '\"'. Then you can scan backward to see if the key matches. `strchr()`is very likely a lot faster than `strncmp()`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I got your point. BTW, I cannot store them to optimize.